# facing issue with in-app purchase of consumable products in android, flutter

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, in-app-purchase, flutter-in-app-purchase

The payment flow is working completely fine, but when the **slow test card is used the consumable product cannot be purchased again.** the plugin used is in_app_purchase: ^3.0.4.
To reproduce the issue:

1. purchase the product with "slow test card, Approves after a few minutes" option.
2. once initiated then close the application.
3. open the application. The purchase stream will be triggered and `await InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);` will successfully run for that purchase.
   But after that, when I try to purchase the product, the google play in-app-purchases handler throws an **error: You already own this item**.
   The whole process works successfully when app is not closed in the process.

and also i'm not able to convert that product back to consumable.

code snippet

```
purchaseParam=PurchaseParam(productDetails:selectedProduct);
InAppPurchase.instance.buyConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);
```

```
_subscription = purchaseUpdated.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
      log("initiating purchase stream");
      p_purchaseList = purchaseDetailsList;
      listenToPurchaseUpdated(purchaseDetailsList);
    }, onDone: () {
      log("done..");
      _subscription.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      log("error in payment is = $error");
    }, 
);
```

```
void listenToPurchaseUpdated(List<PurchaseDetails> purchaseDetailsList) async {
  log("listening to purchases 1 ");
  purchaseDetailsList.forEach((PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) async {
    if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.pending) {
    } else {
      if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.error||purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.canceled) {
        print("error :${purchaseDetails.error!}");
      }
      else if (purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased || purchaseDetails.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
        FirebaseDataStorage().uploadPurchaseInfo(purchaseDetails); // performing tasks once product is purchased
      }
      if (purchaseDetails.pendingCompletePurchase) {
        log("listening to purchases 5 ");
        await InAppPurchase.instance.completePurchase(purchaseDetails);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

the stream is listened in initstate

```
flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.0, on macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-x64, locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 3.0.0 at /Users/anubhav/Library/Developer/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision ee4e09cce0 (10 days ago), 2022-05-09 16:45:18 -0700
    • Engine revision d1b9a6938a
    • Dart version 2.17.0
    • DevTools version 2.12.2

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    • Android SDK at /Users/anubhav/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-32, build-tools 32.1.0-rc1
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.3

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.12+0-b1504.28-7817840)

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • 2201117TI (mobile)                  • 7a310cf0                             • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
    • iPhone SE (3rd generation) (mobile) • 27BC18C4-21F5-43EA-A7F1-9A0DC41FF182 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-5 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)                     • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.2.1 21D62 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)                        • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 101.0.4951.64

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available
```

Comment: Have you finished this bug? I faced same issue.